# Adding labels and colours to Chart.JS from arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, chart.js

I've checked all the other answers and I haven't found what I'm looking for. I'm trying to add JSON data to my chart and I have been successful in adding some of the data, but the labels all appear as one string and my colour only generates once, meaning that only one section of the pie chart has any colour. This is how I declare my arrays and read the data into them.

```
var labels = [];
var failureData = [];

data.map(function(item) {
    labels.push(item.operatorDescription);
});

data.map(function(item) {
    failureData.push(item.failureCount);
});
```

This is how I'm attempting to load my chart.

```
var config = {
    type : 'pie',
    data : {
        datasets : [ {

            data : failureData,

            backgroundColor : [ randomColour()],

        } ],
        labels : [ labels ]
    },
    options : {
        responsive : true
    }
};
```

The variable called failureData goes into the sections on the chart just fine, but the labels are all bunched together in a single section and the colour only generates once.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
I've gotten past the labels issue by replacing

```
labels :  [ labels ]
```

with

```
labels: labels
```

Colours are still an issue though, it's just spreading a single colour across all parts now.

Edit 2:
I've solved the other issue by creating an array of random colour data and passing that in as the colours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gotten past the labels issue by replacing

```
labels :  [ labels ]
```

with

```
labels: labels
```

I've solved the other issue by creating an array of random colour data and passing that in as the colours.